# Plotting a tangent plane in matplotlib using gradients

Tags: python, calculus

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not sure why I am getting an error that traces back to my grad function.

[image: n/a]

When I remove the tangent plane surface, I will get the other surface just fine.

[image: n/a]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
z = lambda x, y : (-(x**2 + y**2))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z(x, y), cmap = 'jet')
```

...instead of:

```
z = (-(x**2 + y**2))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap = 'jet')
```

That gives me:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTXsx.png)

You are defining "z" as a Numpy array, calculated based on two other Numpy arrays "x" and "y". "z" is therefore not a function, and not "callable".

Your function "grad" requires the first positional argument "f" to be a function, which it then "calls". When you pass "z" to "grad", and grad tries to "call z", you receive the "numpy.ndarray object is not callable" error" - because "z" is a numpy.ndarray object, that you are trying to "call".

The above solution redefines "z" as a function, which takes in "x" and "y". You can then pass it into grad as you originally intended. To use it in plot_surface, you have to pass it in not as "z" on its own, but "z" called with the two arrays "x" and "y", which returns your original "z".

In case it's confusing,

```
z = lambda x, y: (-(x**2 + y**2))
```

is just shorthand for

```
def z(x, y):
    return (-(x**2 + y**2))
```

Hope that makes sense, good luck.